# Are nested structs the same size as flattened structs?

Tags: c++, struct

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct A { int x; };
struct B { A a; char y; };
struct C { B b; double z; };
struct D { C c; void *alpha; };
struct E { D d; float beta; };

struct F {
    int x; char y; double z; void *alpha; float beta;
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(sizeof(E) == sizeof(F), "Whoops!");
}
```

The above works and gives me the same sizes.  But I'd prefer a guarantee that this will always be true.  Will it?

Comment: Remember that structure padding and member alignment might play a role here.

Comment: Try adding some `virtual` function inbetween the nesting chain and compare sizes.

Comment: Nice call!  [They are not the same](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/909b73fb0140b0e3).  If you make your comment an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @BrianRodriguez That's only one form to break it. The other comments/answers about alignment optimizations are more basic causes why it's not guaranteed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they need not be the same. The sizes of the two alternatives need not be different either, it will depend on the situation, but as Joachim mentions in the comments padding does play a role. Focusing on the simpler types, those with standard-layout (and in the example a POD, which is slightly more restrictive):

```
struct A { int a; };         // 4 aligned, size 4
struct B { A a; char ch; };  // 4 aligned, size 8
struct C { B b; char ch2; }; // 4 aligned, size 12
```

The reason is that, to provide the right alignment for the `int` member in `B`, the compiler (not mandated, but most compilers aim to have natural alignment) injects 3 bytes of padding after the `ch` member. When `B` is used inside `C`, it requires 8 bytes (including 3 of padding), after adding `ch2` the compiler injects additional padding and ends up wasting a total of 6 bytes.

```
struct D { int a; char ch; char ch2; };
```

In this case, the natural alignment of `ch` and `ch2` is 1, so there is no padding between the two members. There will be some padding at the end of the structure (in this case 2 bytes) but there will be less total padding.